# Does dstat captures disk i/o by the OS prefetching?

Tags: performance, disk-usage, disk

I ran a program which sequentially reads a big file.
The transfer rate [MB/sec] is strictly controlled by the application as 5MB/sec.

However, when I monitored the disk i/o bandwidth usage using dstat tool, the read BW is lower than 5 MB/sec (~3MB/sec)

The most probable cause is the case where the error comes from my application code.

But I want check whether it is possible cause as well:

Does dstat capture disk i/o by the OS prefetching as well? Because the access pattern is sequential, OS will perform excessive read-ahead prefetching operations. (I am using Linux)

Can any one give me an idea on this?

Comment: How much lower is the bandwidth in `dstat`. Could it be that it is a conversion error KiB vs kB ( 1024 vs. 1000 )? It also could be that caching is causing what you observe.